# Fast switching between routers?

Tags: networking, windows-7, router, ping, isp

At home, I have two routers, each one connected to a different ISP. However, they're both really unstable, since ISP A may sometimes stop working for 5 minutes and ISP B has horrible speeds at night.

I am a gamer so I really can't have this kind of interrumptions, but changing ISPs is out of my hands right now. At this time, when I have a problem I just unplug and plug the net cable to the other router; but by the 3rd broken cable you realise that there must be a better solution.

I have a hud switch at home, so my idea is to connect my computer and both routers to it. But how can i configure Windows to work with conflicting IPs or some other issue? And where can I change connections (like you can with Wifi).

Comment: Home? Gamer? Consumer ISPs? Better luck on SU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to recycle an old computer you have laying around and install [Vyatta](http://www.vyatta.com/) on it, as it can do WAN load balancing.

Comment: Some OpenWRT-like firmware had load balancing stuff too.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier for you to buy router which supports connecting 2 WAN connections. There are plenty of routers like that. Just pick one and it will do all the work for switching between 1 ISP and another automatically. Problem is how it should decide one is better then the other. This may be a bit tricker but it's still a better solutions then having 2 separate routers and juggling with cables or doing ROUTE changing in Windows with 2 ethernet cards connected.